# Progress bar loader at the top of div using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a progress bar(similar to the pace.js progress bar). The issue is when browser is refreshed, `pace.js progressbar` is `loading on the top of body, not on the top of div`. The loader should not load on browser refresh but on click of button and inside div at the top.

The objective is to achieve loader like - when we login to Google; there is a progress bar at the top. I am trying to achieve similar functionality.

I have tried using `pace.js`. However, if some other more configurable and flexible library is available, it is welcomed in order to solve problem.

```js
function createDiv(event) {
  event.target.disabled = true;
  var html = '';
  html += '<div id="paceProgressBarBox" style="background:#ccc;width:200px;height:200px;"></div>';
  $('#myDiv').append(html)
  // add pace progress bar at the top of id="paceProgressBarBox"  and stop pace progress bar loading on browser referesh // instead show pace progress bar on click of button
  var pace;
  pace.options.target = '#paceProgressBarBox';
  pace.start();
}
```

```css
.pace {
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.pace-inactive {}

.pace .pace-progress {
  background: #2299dd;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js">
</script>
<br/>
<button onclick="createDiv(event)">Change Content</button>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: It may help to include a specific question. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve or what's going wrong with the code you've written.

Comment: @showdev, updated question. Hope it should help you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<body>` element is hard-coded into pace.js as the element to which the progress bar is attached.
However, you can override it with the `target` setting (which doesn't seem to appear in the [documentation](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/)).

There are two ways to set the `target`:

1. Configure a `paceOptions` variable before loading the pace script:

   ```
   paceOptions = {
     target: '#myDiv'
   }
   ```

   Working example:

   ```css
       #myDiv {
         width: 200px;
         height: 200px;
       }

       .pace .pace-progress {
         position: relative;
         background: #2299dd;
         z-index: 2000;
         right: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         height: 5px;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
       </script>

       <script>
         paceOptions = {
           target: '#myDiv'
         }
       </script>

       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js">
       </script>

       <button>Change Content</button>
       <div id="myDiv"></div>
   ```
2. Configure the progress bar in its `<script>` tag:

   ```
   <script src=".../pace.js" data-pace-options='{ "target": "#myDiv" }'></script>
   ```

   Working example:

   ```css
       #myDiv {
         width: 200px;
         height: 200px;
       }

       .pace .pace-progress {
         position: relative;
         background: #2299dd;
         z-index: 2000;
         right: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         height: 5px;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
       </script>

       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js" data-pace-options='{ "target": "#myDiv" }'>
       </script>

       <button>Change Content</button>
       <div id="myDiv"></div>
   ```

---

For reference, see:
[Pace Configuration](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/#configuration)
[Specify Location of Indicator](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/11)

---

### Edit:

To prevent Pace from starting automatically upon page load, set the `startOnPageLoad` setting to `false`:

```js
jQuery('#changeContent').on('click', createDiv);
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.pace .pace-progress {
  position: relative;
  background: #2299dd;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}

#paceProgressBarBox {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  var paceOptions = {
    'startOnPageLoad': false,
    'target': '#paceProgressBarBox'
  }

  function createDiv(event) {
    event.target.disabled = true;
    var $progBarBox = $('<div>', {
      'id': 'paceProgressBarBox'
    });
    $('#myDiv').append($progBarBox);
    Pace.start();
  }
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js">
</script>

<button id="changeContent">Change Content</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Also see:
[Pace's source code](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/master/pace.coffee) for a full list of options
[How to stop pace js plugin to run on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057017/how-to-stop-pace-js-plugin-to-run-on-page-load-i-want-to-fix-only-on-ajax-reque)

Comment: Thanks, but It is loading when page get loaded or when browser is refreshed. However, it should load only when function is called onclick of button, not when page loads.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I've edited my answer to address that.